# Iterative eigensolver allowing initial guess and complex eigenvalues?

Tags: julia, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a time-dependent complex matrix `A(t)`, and I want to follow its eigenvalues over time. In other words, in the time-dependent list of eigenvalues `a[1](t), ..., a[n](t)`, I want each entry to change continuously over time.

One approach is to find the eigendecomposition of `A(t+ε)` iteratively, using the eigendecomposition of `A(t)` as an initial guess. Since the guess is almost correct, the iteration should only change it slightly, giving the desired continuity.

I think the [LOBPCG](https://julialinearalgebra.github.io/IterativeSolvers.jl/dev/eigenproblems/lobpcg/) and [SVD](https://julialinearalgebra.github.io/IterativeSolvers.jl/dev/svd/svdl/) solvers in IterativeSolvers.jl can do this, because they let you store the iterator state. Unfortunately, they only work for matrices with real eigenvalues. (The SVG solver also requires real entries.) The solvers in [ArnoldiMethod.jl](https://haampie.github.io/ArnoldiMethod.jl/stable/usage/01_getting_started.html) can handle complex eigenvalues, but doesn't seem to allow an initial guess. Is there any available eigensolver that has both the features I need?