# Is there a faster way to get eigenvalues/vectors when good initial guess is given?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

As far as I know, `numpy.eig` and `scipy.eig` are from `LAPACK`, and the algorithm is based on iterative method.
If we assume that the good initial guess for eigen values and eigen vectors are given (very close to the real eigenvals/vectors), is there any chance to imporve the convergence speed of eigendecomposition?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand( 100, 100 )
LAM, W = np.linalg.eig(A)

A2 = A + 0.001 * np.random.rand( 100, 100 ) # similar matrix to A 
LAM2, W2 = eig_with_initial_guess(A2, guess = (LAM,W))
```

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're trying to solve

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I want to improve the speed of np.linalg.eig with initial guess for eigen values and eigen vectors. I found a similar post here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120716/iterative-eigensolver-allowing-initial-guess-and-complex-eigenvalues

Comment: `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` is iterative https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs. Where did you read that the other `eig` are iterative?  There's nothing in the docs about that, nor anything about initial values.

Comment: `numpy.linalg.eig` appears to be a wrapper for `SGEEV`. The one LAPACK implementation I looked at seems to use QR iteration to compute the eigenvalues. https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/8254fbdd80f6ff5362db122538433389e55eaeab/SRC/sgeev.f#L413

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to provide an initial guess for `np.linalg.eig`. If you've a good guess and want some polishing, you can make a few inverse iteration steps manually. Or use ARPACK via `scipy.sparse.linalg`.